# Translate this code from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Hi i have a simple question, i want to translate this code

```
CGSize cellSize = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout).itemSize;
```

to swift, anyone has any idea of how?

Comment: Have you tried converting it? If yes, please post your tries and the issues you run into.

Comment: not really, im a noob in this two laguages... any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Then you have to learn the languages. This line code is not complex at all, and if you don't know how to translate this, then you won't be able to face real challenges in your project.

Comment: Thank's @Cristik, i will.

Comment: if any type of syntax issue . you can refer this link. this gives you hint to convert code from objective c to swift "https://objectivec2swift.com/"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
var cellSize: CGSize = (self.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize
```

Comment: Please don't give code samples that use forced casts, especially to newcomers to the language.

Comment: @Cristik -- I agree your points, I am also faced the same issue when I Start to learn swift, some times we give good start up it will encourage to learn ,

Comment: thats a like good spirit man

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - tanx bro...